# My HP ProLiant DL380G7 give Correctable ECC logging reached?

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, memory, hp-proliant, ecc

I have a HP Pro Liant DL380G7 and a VMWare ESXi installed on it. In configuration tab of vSphere client inventory Memory Status is *Warning* with this message "System Board 8 Memory: Correctable ECC logging limit reached - Assert".
Is it serious? How can i correct it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just an ECC ram error. It means that the threshold for error correction on one of your DIMMS has been exceeded. This is a warranty issue, so call it in to HP and they'll send you a new memory module.

Also see: [How seriously should I take ECC correctable error warnings?](https://serverfault.com/questions/144151/how-seriously-should-i-take-ecc-correctable-error-warnings)

Comment: There's probably an amber light on the front panel indicating what DIMM is bad too.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a [BIOS upgrade](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=4091408&swItem=MTX-822b75f01df447d1aa2430ba96&prodNameId=4091409&swEnvOID=4091&swLang=8&taskId=135&mode=4&idx=0) to fix this.